# Stop punctuation marks from adding new lines android

Tags: android

I'm building an android app that generates random passwords. The passwords also contain symbols and punctuation marks for optimal variety. But Android always puts newlines after each puncuation mark because it interpreted the random characters as words. I've tried adding `android:singleLine="true"` but that just wraps text on one line instead of removing the newlines. Any ideas on how to fix this? This is a picture that shows what I mean:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... the first generated password starts with an "!" and it does not start a new line until the second one is generated.

Comment: I believe the issue he wants solved is when you have a symbol, such as '!', ',', etc, it groups alphabet characters together and symbols together, so when a symbol occurs the large clump of alphabet characters moves to the next line because it isn't 'grouped' with the symbol, and because it is to long to fit on the screen.

Comment: The text shown in the picture is 1 password. I don't want that android splits the line after punctuation marks. I'd rather like that it fills a line with characters until it's full and then start with the next line instead of starting a new line after each bunch of letters.